# How does the Torricelli barometer create a vacuum at the top of the tube?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science, vacuum, air

[image]

Hi everyone! 
Can someone explain to me how does the Torricelli barometer creates a vacuum at the top of the tube? And how does it work?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Pascal's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_law)?

Comment: [Wikipedia: Barometer: Mercury barometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer#Mercury_barometers) has a good explanation.

Comment: @PM 2Ring no i am not familiar with Pascal's Law